# Numpy array automatically converts to integer

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to normalize an array of values, but when I put it in the numpy array, it automatically converts the values to integers. Code is below:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,2],[3,1],[3,5],[4,6],[3,4]])
s = np.std(data[:,0])
m = np.mean(data[:,0])
temp = (data[:,0] - m) 
temp /= s

print(temp)
data[:,0] = temp
print(data)
```

and the result is this:

```
[-0.86266219 -1.40182605  0.75482941  1.29399328  0.21566555]
[[ 1  0]
 [ 3 -1]
 [ 3  0]
 [ 4  1]
 [ 3  0]]
```

Why does it automatically convert to integer when I put it into numpy? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the problem here?  It now takes up too little space?

Comment: I want the second column of "data" to be [-0.86266219 -1.40182605  0.75482941  1.29399328  0.21566555], but it's showing [0, -1, 0, 1, 0]

Comment: Anything put into an integer `dtype` array is converted to an integer.  Arrays don't hold mixed data types.  You need to collect the normalized values in a float dtype array.  (And any thing inserted into that array will become a float!).

Comment: I don't like the duplicate link because he should not be trying to convert `data` in-place to float.  `data` is integer, and should remain that way.